# Thread deadlocking and synchronization

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I know that I need to use synchronization *appropriately* in order to avoid deadlocking when using multiple threads, but I was wondering:

Do I need to synchronize for both *amending the value of* and *examining* a variable, or do I just need to synchronize when I *amend* the value, but not when I *examine* the variable?

Comment: Synchronization does *not* avoid deadlocks, it causes them when not used correctly.

Comment: @Darkhogg that's what I meant. Hopefully my update reflects this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the deadlocking: Darkhogg already correctly pointed out that deadlocking is a result from incorrect synchronization and workflow.

Synchronizing state modifications and state observation: Yes, you need to synchronize both. The effect of the object lock you obtain when entering a synchronized method is that no other thread my enter the same or another synchronized code block that requires the same object lock (synhronizes on the same object). That said, if you do not synchronize the code that observes the state of your object, then this code might be executed concurrently to the synchronized code that modifies the state and you may read an invalid object state.

Answer (score 1):

as Darkhogg mentioned synchronization causes deadlocks if not used properly.

You need to synchronize code blocks on a data members that are updating(changing data members) the value and can be executed by multiple thread.

Make it synchronized will insure that the data members will not be updated simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What if only one of my threads (thread A) updates and the other threads (threads B+) just access the data value. Do threads B+ have to synchronize access?

Comment: just accessing or reading data is not a critical section of the code so you don't need to synchronize that part of the code

Comment: but doesn't this contradict Raif's answer?

Comment: @ralf is right you should have a ReadLock as well. Reading does not affect consistency of the object but it might lead to a dirty ready. While a value of the member is getting changed and you read the value it could be a intermediate value which ultimately gets changed. Having a read lock makes your operation slow but it's safe to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Read that article this my get you better knowledge base about synchronization
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a resource that is not thread-safe, you'll need to protect both examining and amending its value.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized do not use to avoid deadlock

> Synchronize keyword ensure thread safely in multithreading environment. Though you have a multi thread, you want to amending and examining member variables.

To do it create a class which contains data variables that you want to thread safed. create synchronized function for appending and examining variables.

```
class exam
{
 ....

 synchronized void examine()
 {}


 synchronized void amending()
 {}


}
```

create a single object of the class and pass it to your all thread.